# How to return nothing from a function that returning value?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree, and I want to delete a node.

I need to get its parent, so I wrote a function:

```
private BSTreeNode<T> getParent(BSTreeNode<T> root, BSTreeNode<T> node) {
        if(root == null) 
            return null;
        if(node.element().lessThan(root.element())) {
            if(root.getLeft() != null && root.getLeft().element().equal(node.element())) 
                return root;
            else
                getParent(root.getLeft(), node);
        } else {
            if(root.getRight() != null && root.getRight().element().equal(node.element()))
                return root;
            else
                getParent(root.getRight(), node);
        }
    }
```

Unlike C/C++, Java is giving me the following error:

```
This method must return a result of type BSTreeNode<T>
```

It forces me to return a value in the last line of the function.

How can I fix it in the context of my function?

Comment: Use `return getParent...`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis and use which parameters?

Comment: I don't know, that's part of your design. The point is your method must always return something if your return type is different than `void`.

Comment: C and C++ compilers may not force you to return a value for non-void return types, but that doesn't mean it's "allowed". If the function terminates without a return (or exception) the result is undefined. Java is just particularly keen on enforcing this rule.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh, my fault. I confused a minute that I have to return value in all the else-if blocks. thank you so much!

Comment: If you only want to return a value sometimes (as in the `return root` cases above) then return `null` for the other cases.  All possible exit points must return a value (or not), consistent with the method definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function does not have a return for every possible circumstance. You have:

```
if (null)...

if (less than root)...
else ( if ...)
       else (no return!)
```

What do you return if it is not null, and goes to the final else? Nothing is returned.

You can either `return getParent...` in the else statement. or `return null` at the end of the function (not in an if or else statement)

I often see code like so to cover the event of neither if statement returning a value.

```
public int getAnswer()
{
    if (answer.equals("yes"))
        return 0;
    else if (answer.equals("no"))
        return 1;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: That's correct. You need to have a return in every branche of your if/else statements.

Answer (score 2):

You should be good with this:

```
private BSTreeNode<T> getParent(BSTreeNode<T> root, BSTreeNode<T> node) {
    if(root == null) 
        return null;
    if(node.element().lessThan(root.element())) {
        if(root.getLeft() != null && root.getLeft().element().equal(node.element())) 
            return root;
        else
            return getParent(root.getLeft(), node);
    } else {
        if(root.getRight() != null && root.getRight().element().equal(node.element()))
            return root;
        else
            return getParent(root.getRight(), node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add return null; statement at the end of the method .
I think this statement will be unreachable in normal cases but add it just to fix the compilation error and try what will happen.

```
private BSTreeNode<T> getParent(BSTreeNode<T> root, BSTreeNode<T> node) {
        if(root == null) 
            return null;
        if(node.element().lessThan(root.element())) {
            if(root.getLeft() != null && root.getLeft().element().equal(node.element())) 
                return root;
            else
                getParent(root.getLeft(), node);
        } else {
            if(root.getRight() != null && root.getRight().element().equal(node.element()))
                return root;
            else
                getParent(root.getRight(), node);
        }
return null;
    }
```

Comment: It always return `null`.

Comment: No man , Check it well the return statement will only execute if all the conditions fail and that's clearly the same as the answer that you supported above . So please remove the down vote :)